# What happens in the Android OS when there's too many applications "sleeping" in the background?

Tags: android, operating-system

I've been reading that Android (like most of mobile OS's) doesn't "exit" applications.

When we press the back button, the application is still in the background (like an iddle state).

So, I'd like to know, what doees it do when there's too many apps running in the background?

Answer (score 6):

From [official Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles):

> The Android system tries to maintain
>   an application process for as long as
>   possible, but eventually it will need
>   to remove old processes when memory
>   runs low. To determine which processes
>   to keep and which to kill, Android
>   places each process into an
>   "importance hierarchy" based on the
>   components running in it and the state
>   of those components. Processes with
>   the lowest importance are eliminated
>   first, then those with the next
>   lowest, and so on.

From a user's perspective, the more memory an Android device has, the better. Why? Applications that aren't used are "idle" and take up a part of device's RAM.

Every time you start an application from zero, that is, an application that isn't idle, Android's CPU will use up resources to bring it to life and into memory.

When an app goes into idle mode and, later, back into active mode, it won't use up that much CPU. And CPU usage is the main battery drainer, if we don't take GPS, WI-FI and Bluetooth into account.

So, what does this all mean? You want applications that you use often to reside in memory, so that CPU isn't used as much. Android will keep them alive, based on priority.

This is the reason why task killers are a bad idea, and this is why they won't work anymore in Android 2.2, Froyo.

Answer (score 1):

Oh the usual, android just goes on a killing spree

```
    Line 8544: 01-24 18:41:30.610 I/am_kill ( 2474): [5601,com.google.android.youtube,12,too many background]
    Line 8655: 01-24 18:42:15.637 I/am_kill ( 2474): [5995,com.sec.android.app.camera:CropImage,12,too many background]
    Line 8714: 01-24 18:42:26.505 I/am_kill ( 2474): [5961,com.sec.android.app.camera,12,too many background]
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity gets killed. This should not be a problem, because the developer read this manual, and coded for it :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles

Answer (score 0):

Define 'too many'. :-)

Idle apps don't use resources (unless specifically programmed to do so).

If the phone goes low on memory, the apps with the lowest priority are killed and memory reclaimed.

Task killers on Android are inherently unnecessary.

Read more about this here: [Why You Shouldn’t Be Using a Task Killer with Android](http://geekfor.me/faq/you-shouldnt-be-using-a-task-killer-with-android/)

Answer (score 0):

When the operating system needs more capacity for new activities to run, it shuts down background tasks. So for example if you start the Browser application, which has large resource requirements, many background activities will be shut down.

You can write Android applications to run as a Service though, and they will not be shut down, and will continue to run in the background.

Read these topics for more details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Android manages the task of asking Activities to finish when it wants to reallocate resources.

From the "Application Fundamentals" page on the developer guide:

> If an activity is paused or stopped,
>   the system can drop it from memory
>   either by asking it to finish (calling
>   its finish() method), or simply
>   killing its process. When it is
>   displayed again to the user, it must
>   be completely restarted and restored
>   to its previous state

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lcycles

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Android lets processes run in the background until it needs the resources, at which point it kills some of these processed to reclaim the memory.

[Here](http://geekfor.me/faq/you-shouldnt-be-using-a-task-killer-with-android/) is a link to a good explanation of the issue, it is at the root of the "Do I Need a Task Killer" issue many Android users argue over.