# Android application crashes randomly

Tags: android, crash

I have a strange problem, which is my application crashes sometimes. It is random. When I checked it on emulator and I didn't get an app crash. My app doesn’t use internet, no hardware access. But randomly it crashes when it is on the mobile. What can be the reasons? Is there any clues or hints reveal this? I am sorry; I don't have anymore information regarding this.

Please note that it doesn't crash when I use it. Most of the times I notice that this problem happens when phone is in idol state or use another application. Mobile task manager shows app use about 30 MB of ram.

Comment: Check the LogCat, post it and your code to be able to assist you

Comment: I think logcat is MUST for getting anywhere near crash reason. Try to run your app on device while connected to eclipse. You might get logcat if it crashes then

Comment: Without more information, we're sorry but we cannot answer -- we have no way to know. You need to collect your crash logs in order to have a clue what is going on. You might look into adding ACRA (Android Crash Reporting) to your application.

Comment: please give me sometimes, I will back with ACRA reports

Comment: You need to post the details from logcat about why it crashed for anyone to be able to help

Comment: As I mentioned it happens when phone is idle or other application is runnning. I think this link give a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957558/what-happens-in-the-android-os-when-theres-too-many-applications-sleeping-in but I need to check this more.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, an app crashes due to the following reasons:
1. If an exception is not properly handled or caught.
2. Memory management problems.
3. Bandwidth fluctuation issues in the internet connection.

Judging by your question, it seems like the second point is more relevant. 30MB of a device RAM is a tad too much.

It will be a bit more helpful if you give the details of crash in the LogCat

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your phone memory is it free to expand its files, if not, it may create crash.

Comment: is there way to remove application from memory when I don't use it. I think you may be correct.

Comment: go to setting and uninstall the application or clear the data of not required apps.

Comment: App can be remove from  mememory but why does it crash?